# Make excel only display two decimal places

Tags: excel

I've tried various things and nothing is working out quite like it should.  I've used the `office button, excel options, advanced, and set the automatic insert decimal place to 0'.`  `Then I tried the format cells, and set the decimal places to 2` method.  Nothing gives me what I want.  I either end up with whole numbers with two decimal places e.g. 23.00 or when i enter 5.23 into a cell I only get '23' showing up.

Is there a way to show whole numbers without decimal places and have excel never show more than 2 decimal places in non-whole numbers?

Comment: A custom format of "0.##" gives a result close to what you seek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the cell to display maximum of 2 decimal places (and none for whole numbers) by applying the format 0.## in FormatCells -> Number Tab -> Custom -> Type.  See [this conversation](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/560141-show-decimal-point-only-if-not-a-whole-number.html) for more details